# My code does not run unless I change the order of a script file

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript files, one called app.js, the other ui.js. The ui.js file is where I have an arrow function defined, the app.js is where I call the function. If I include ui.js which includes the function in second place in my index.html file, I get an error saying function apples is not defined. I can obviously change this by putting ui.js first and then app.js and this works. However on a tutorial I'm following, he has app.js included as the first file and gets no error, his code is exactly the same as mine. Why is this?

```
   <div class="car"></div>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="ui.js"></script>

  // UI.JS CODE
  const div = document.querySelector(".car");
  const apples = (data, name) => {
    const html = `<p>${data}</p>
                  <p>${name}</p>`;
    div.innerHTML += html;
  };

  //  App.js
  if (10 > 2) {
    apples("this is the data", "and this is the name");
  }
```

Comment: Does the tutorial by any chance load the scripts with a `defer` tag?

Comment: No its the same as mine

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial and a timestamp?

Comment: Can you link us to this tutorial? Because you definitely can't use what's not declared yet

Comment: For the JS files go to the JS folder https://github.com/iamshaunjp/pwa-tutorial/tree/lesson-25

Comment: I don't think you are following the tutorial. The linked one is much more complicated, the `app.js` installs the service worker and the `ui.js` has its script executed under the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Answer (score 1):

When a web page is loaded by a browser, what normally happens is that the scripts are executed in the order of the scripts being loaded.

That means if `ui.js` is loaded before `app.js`, if the fetching for `ui.js` is completed before `app.js`, it will run before it.
Likewise, if `app.js` is loaded before `ui.js`, it will execute before it.

However, if the scripts are tagged with `async`, they'll get loaded asynchronously.
That means, even if `ui.js` is *loaded* before `app.js` but `app.js` gets **fetched** before `ui.js`, in this case `app.js` will execute before.
This is because when browsers detect the `async` tag, they'll execute scripts as soon as they're completely fetched. This is what might be happening in your case.

So if something thats loaded before the other is called that has a dependency, it's essentially being called without declaration/definition.

Another possibility is also that you're loading the scripts with a `defer` tag, which will only execute the scripts after the page is completely loaded, in which case you'll have to always load the scripts with all dependencies loaded first.

Comment: Since when are scripts executed in arbitrary order when there are no defer/async attribute present?

Comment: If you load 2 scripts, they're loaded asynchronously related to each other. Not to the whole page.

Comment: Maybe ... But they are definitely executed in the order the tags appear on the page. Only setting `async` for a script might mess the executing order (as well as `defer` in some ancient browsers).